# Nest a function to return nothing if the result is "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If the result of the following formula is "0" how do I add to the formula to return nothing-as in the cell stays blank.

> =COUNTIFS(F:F,J6)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `IF` function to check for the result.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(F:F,J6)>0,COUNTIFS(F:F,J6),"")`

If you have Excel 365 you can use a `LET`-function to avoid counting twice:

```
=LET(result,COUNTIFS(F:F,J6),
IF(result>0,result,""))
```

Or you use a special **numberformat** (with your original formula):
`0;;`
which will not show negative numbers and 0

Comment: Good formula suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try-

```
=TEXT(COUNTIFS(F:F,J6),"0;;;")
```